# Custom mapper class is not getting the result?

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am writing a DAO application and I want to get zone data. I have written my own mapper class. I am unable to get values. It is throwing an exception.

**Mapper class**

```
public class zoneMapper implements RowMapper {

    @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

         ZoneBean zone=new ZoneBean();
        zone.setZoneId(resultSet.getInt("ZONE_ID"));
        zone.setZoneName(resultSet.getString("ZONE_NAME"));
        return zone;

    }
```

**dao call**

```
List<ZoneBean> zoneList=new ArrayList<ZoneBean>();
        try {
             JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

             zoneList = (List<ZoneBean>) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                     queriesConstants.GET_ZONES, new zoneMapper());
             }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("getZones "+e.getMessage());
            //logger.error("getZones "+e.getMessage());
        }
 **Exception is**
 getZones Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 17
```

Comment: Problem is that queryForObject is expecting **only one row** and the query has returned 17. Your mapper has not even been executed. Use instead **queryForList** method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getZones Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 17

You retrieve multiple elements when your execute your query.

`public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)` is therefore not suitable for your need because it executes a query given static SQL, mapping **a single result row** to a Java object via a RowMapper.

You should use rather this method :

`public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`which executes a query given static SQL, **mapping each row** to a Java object via a RowMapper.

Comment: Good explanation and my problem solved (+1) let me accept this answer